# How can i create trigger using GROUP BY

Tags: sql-server, group-by

I want to create a trigger after insert and update which calculate the sum of values in multiple rows and set the sum in `[Target_Cummlative]`. I try the following code but that causes this error:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure target_cummlative, Line 13
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FROM

My code:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[target_cummlative] 
ON [dbo].[Appointments]
AFTER insert, UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
    IF TRIGGER_NESTLEVEL() > 1
        RETURN

    UPDATE T1
    SET t1.[Target_Cummlative] = SUM(ISNULL(CAST([TARGET] AS FLOAT), 0)
    FROM [Appointments] T1
    INNER JOIN inserted i ON T1.[UniqueId] = i.[UniqueId]
    GROUP BY CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), t1.[StartDate], 111), t1.[ResourceId]
END
```

Here is what i have currently, as you can see `Target cummlative` is null

```
Id     StartDate           Location ResourceId  TARGET  Target_Cummlative
1381    2019-07-22 07:00:00 41051       1        20        NULL
1382    2019-07-22 08:00:00 41051       1        20        NULL
1383    2019-07-22 09:15:00 41051       1        15        NULL
1384    2019-07-22 10:00:00 41051       1        20        NULL
1385    2019-07-22 11:00:00 41051       1        20        NULL
1386    2019-07-22 12:30:00 41051       1        8         NULL
```

I want set the sum the values in `TARGET` column and update `Target cummlative` as

```
Id     StartDate           Location ResourceId  TARGET  Target_Cummlative
1381    2019-07-22 07:00:00 41051       1        20        103
1382    2019-07-22 08:00:00 41051       1        20        103
1383    2019-07-22 09:15:00 41051       1        15        103
1384    2019-07-22 10:00:00 41051       1        20        103
1385    2019-07-22 11:00:00 41051       1        20        103
1386    2019-07-22 12:30:00 41051       1        8         103
```

Comment: Seems that error is coming up because you are missing the `)` that would close out the SUM operator. It should be `SUM(ISNULL(CAST([TARGET] AS FLOAT),0))`. I haven't tested beyond that.

Comment: @Trevor Yes that resolve it the above error thank you but how can i calculate total. any idea?

Comment: in what way is it not calculating the total if you are using sum?

Comment: @Hogan i want to group multiple row by `start date and [ResourceId]` and do the sum. how can i use GROUP BY?

Comment: The answer provided addresses the question you asked. If you have a different question regarding the actual functionality of your code, have a look at [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), and then pose that as a new question.

Comment: @keven -- I'd guess you should cast the timestamp to a date -- but it is really hard to say -- as eric points out, this question has been answered if you have a different question you should make a new question and ask it.  give starting data and ending data, show what you have done, explain why it does not work. etc.

Comment: Ok thanks @Hogan i added sample data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If possible - I'd advice against storing cumulative data in the same table, if possible - better create a separate one to store aggregated information.

In any case - your issue is missing parenthesis in `SET` clause.

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[target_cumulative]
ON [dbo].[Appointments]
AFTER insert, UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
    IF TRIGGER_NESTLEVEL() > 1
        RETURN

    UPDATE T1
    SET T1.[Target_Cumulative] = SUM(ISNULL(CAST([TARGET] AS FLOAT), 0))
    FROM dbo.Appointments AS T1
    INNER JOIN inserted AS ION I.UniqueId = T1.UniqueId
    GROUP BY CONVERT(DATE, T1.StartDate), T1.ResourceId;
END;
```

Oh - and there's typo in **cummlative**, it should be **cumulative**

Comment: I think you have an extra `)` -- it should be `CONVERT(DATE, T1.StartDate)` right?

Comment: @EvaldasBuinauskas Thanks! but i get `Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure target_cumulative, Line 14
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'GROUP'.`